# Actionscript 3.0 > Local Encrypted Store on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad, flash, air

I have an iOS device which uses LES to save data such as a username, when I delete the application from device (iPad 2) and then re-install the application the LES data remains. 
I'm not sure if this is the expected result but I assumed the data would have been cleared once the app had been deleted.

Can anybody confirm if the data should remain once removed?

The data appears to be cleared when doing the same tests on desktop and Android (Galaxy S3).

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean Encrypted Local Store (ELS). I can't speak for iOS, but on the Windows/OSX desktop, the ELS isn't deleted when uninstalling the application, I always had to use custom installers/uninstallers to delete data located in the application storage directory.

According to the documenation this is the expected behaviour:

> **Limitations of the encrypted local store**
>
> [...] When you uninstall an AIR application, the uninstaller does not delete data stored in the encrypted local store. [...]

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html

Comment: I've no idea why I was calling it Local Encrypted Store, staring at it for too long. Thanks for the help.